# Still fuzzy on creating objects in Code, IB, and combined

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm still quite new to Xcode etc, so Im a bit fuzzy when it comes do creating/using objects in Xcode.

For example, I used a tutorial for creating a GestureRecognizer in code - it's pretty simple.

Right now I have only this in my .h:

```
@interface PlayPage : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```

And this in my .m:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapTwo=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTap)];
[tapTwo setDelegate:self];
[tapTwo setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
[tapTwo setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapTwo]; //adds it to view
```

Here are my question(s):

1) If I also want to see the GestureRecognizer in IB along with the above code (perhaps so I can change some settings since I'm not familiar with everything) how do I accomplish that?

2) How would you decide when to use all code vs. a mix of code/IB ? Is it strictly a matter of style/comfort/familiarity?

3) It seems declaring different objects requires different 'setup' code (UITextLabel vs GestureRecognizer vs UITextField,for example) - how do you know when to use which code?

Thanks for helping to clear this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In Xcode 4.x Interface builder there are `UIGestureRecognizer` objects that you can drag onto your views. So you would need to add the `UIGestureRecognizer` in Interface builder (if you need to do any more config in code then connect them up with an outlet as well).
2. I try and do anything I can in IB and drop to code when I have to but it is a matter of preference.

   - I'd rather eyeball the position of views and use the snap guides than spend a while figuring it out in code.
   - You can hide a lot of boiler plate code if you do it in IB
3. Start typing and look at the autocompletion options to jog your memory. But more importantly every time you use a class you have not used before you should at least skim the documentation to see what is suggested. **Half of the questions on this site could easily be solved if the question poster actually bothered to look at the vast documentation available.**

---

**Update**

You need to create the `UIGestureRecognizer` in Interface Builder not your code.

In Interface Builder ensure that the `Utilities` pain is visible and drag and drop a `UIGestureRecognizer` of the required class onto your view

This is what the `UIGestureRecognizer` class look like:

[image: UIGestureRecognizer subclasses]

You then configure the object in the `Utilities` panel. If you want to be able to access this object in your code then you will need an `IBOutlet`.

In your classes header file add a new ivar for this

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer;
```

In the implementation file synthesize this

```
@synthesize tapGestureRecognizer = _tapGestureRecognizer;
```

Then back in Interface builder connect this up by `ctrl` + `click` + `dragging` from the `File's Owner` to the `UIGestureRecognizer` subclass. Then selecting your ivar from the window that appears:

[image]

[image]

Comment: @paul.s Perhaps I should be clearer with my question - I'm not sure of all the code chunks I need to add to my original posted code if I want to also be able to see the GR in IB...

Comment: Just FYI - I do read/skim the docs, but I'm new to Objective-C and Xcode, and to be honest, I find the docs lacking. I'm from a Visual Studio background and their docs are much clearer and have embedded sample code chunks. Plus, C requires more effort to declare and use objects and vars, so it takes some getting used to. Usually I can find tutorials that are much clearer. Also, the StackOverflow community has been immeasurably helpful.

Comment: The docs are not aimed at teaching people new to the language ad framework. Once you understand the language and have had exposure to enough classes you don't want to read a load of bumph just to find out what a method does (hence the class documentation is generally fairly succinct). What might be of more use is the `Application programming guides` that Apple also has. These will be slightly closer to a tutorial style with some sample code.

Comment: Also I was not even suggesting that you don't read the manuals, I was simply answering your question "how do you know when to use which code?".

Comment: @Paul.s Thanks - I'll check out the App Prog Guides - it seems those will have the info I'm after.